# Excel export another sheet reference error

Tags: excel, apache-poi, birt

I am working on BIRT report. In this I can successfully export Excel formula when export to Excel with the use of spudsoft emitter that comes default with BIRT. The problem is when I reference a sheet from an another sheet it throws error. Like in BIRT report I have two tables: first table name is table1  and second table name is table2 (so that this name is used as sheet name) both first table has pagebreak after always, so two sheets will be created. When I export it to Excel, the Excel report with two sheets 'table1' and 'table2' created successfully (without a formula that refer another sheet).

When a column of table1(sheet1) is refered from table2 (sheet2) it refers and exported report works successfully.

example-1
     a column in table2 refer a value of table1 column( B,the code for that table2 dataelement  onRender event is

```
if((reportContext.getRenderOption().outputFormat == "xlsx" )||(reportContext.getRenderOption().outputFormat == "XLSX"))
{
    p  = row.__rownum;
    this.text="table1!B"+prow;
}
```

it exports and refer the table1 value correctly.

But when refering a column of table2 from table1, this time it throws error.Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..0)

example-2
a column in table1 refer a value of table2 column(C),the code for that table1 dataelement  onRender event is

```
if((reportContext.getRenderOption().outputFormat == "xlsx" )||(reportContext.getRenderOption().outputFormat == "XLSX"))
{
    p  = row.__rownum;
    this.text="table2!C"+prow;
}
```

My assumption is when table1 is generated that time table2 is not available. If this is the correct assumption, then my solution is to changing the order of element while rendering (I don't have idea for the possibility).

Error in the exported Excel sheet is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..0) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(XSSFWorkbook.java:1043) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.getSheetName(XSSFWorkbook.java:876) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getSheetNameByExternSheet(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:135) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.XSSFFormulaUtils$1.getSheetNameByExternSheet(XSSFFormulaUtils.java:81) at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.ExternSheetNameResolver.prependSheetName(ExternSheetNameResolver.java:42) at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.Ref3DPtg.toFormulaString(Ref3DPtg.java:91) at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaRenderer.toFormulaString(FormulaRenderer.java:92) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.XSSFFormulaUtils.updateFormula(XSSFFormulaUtils.java:126) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.XSSFFormulaUtils.updateSheetName(XSSFFormulaUtils.java:106) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.setSheetName(XSSFWorkbook.java:1230) at uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.handlers.PageHandler.endPage(PageHandler.java:225) at uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.ExcelEmitter.endPage(ExcelEmitter.java:296) at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.endContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:102) at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.DummyPageBuffer.endContainer(DummyPageBuffer.java:61) at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.end(HTMLPageLM.java:183) at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:98) at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100) at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask$PageRangeRender.render(RenderTask.java:717) at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:321) ... 39 more
```

The problem is when sheet1 is in generation it refers sheet2, at this time sheet2 is not available, so the error thrown, but can we change the order order of element execution in the generation phase and on rendering phase roll back to the previous position.

I cannot change the order because the sheet1 should be showed first, then only sheet2.

Any idea related to my issue in BIRT?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the most recent (currently 3.13 final), what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am using spudsoft soft emitter of BIRT runtime jar. This jar use apache poi.my jar is org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.4.1.v20140916-1320.jar

Comment: did you find the answer?? I'm facing the same issue here

Comment: @Victor are you using birt?

Comment: @mani , no , I'm having similar issue in Java...

Comment: @Victor try to rearrange the sheets I mean if you forward reference then change the index of the sheet you are referring.. I assume sheet2 can't reference a value in sheet1, give a try changing the index of sheet2 to sheet1 and viceversa, and then recalculate the workbook.